# Standard deviation in every quarter-hour in R

Tags: r, time-series, standard-deviation

I have raw data of power system frequency. 86 400 numbers.

```
 frequency=a$Ist_Frq

 plot.ts(frequency, main="System frequency [Hz]", xlab="Time [s]")
```

See example:

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rCk0.jpg)

Now, i have to determine quarter-hour time interval.

```
 frequency=ts(a$Ist_Frq, start=1, frequency=900)

[quarter-hour time interval][2]
```

My question is:

Is there any way how to determine standart deviation in every quarter-hour?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Sorry, it is my first question on stackoverflow

Comment: no problem. this is why we review postings here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably several solutions to this problem: here is one

```
#some data
x <- rnorm(10000)

#identify quarter hour segments 
y <- rep(1:ceiling(length(x)/(15 * 60)), each = 15 * 60)[1:length(x)]

#use tapply to find sd of x for every value of y
tapply(x, y, sd)
```

nb the last value might be based on fewer than 900 values